# How to add a dotted line or add padding to td border

Tags: html, css, outline, border-spacing

The below image is already close to the solution i am looking for (see [my codepen](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/MWOBdrz?editors=1100)). The only thing that is missing is a padding / gap between the outline border of `<tbody>` or `<thead>` and the border of the `<td>`

[image: table with dotted lines current state]

#### Questions

- What approach would you take if you had to create something that looks like the image above?
- How can i achieve that the dotted lines have some gap between the border of the td (/ tr) and the outline of either tr or tbody or table?

#### Code

You can take a look at the [code on codepen](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/MWOBdrz?editors=1100). My CSS approach is this

```css
table {  width: 100%; }
/** outline: 0.5pt solid; outline-color: black; border-spacing: .2em 0em; **/

thead, tbody { outline: 0.5pt solid; outline-color: black; }

th.sgn { border-bottom: 1pt dotted blue; padding-top: 1ex;}    
td.sgn { border-bottom: 1pt dotted blue; padding-top: 1ex;}
```

```html
<table>
       <colgroup>
         <col width="20%">
         <col width="35%">                    
         <col width="15%">
         <col width="30%">                    
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>Werkzeugnr:</th>
            <th class="sgn"> &nbsp; </th>
            <th>Index</td><th class="sgn"></th>
       </tr>                            
       <tr class="sml">
            <th colspan="4"> &nbsp; </th>
       </tr>                            
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan="4"><h3>Bitte ausfüllen und abheften!</h3></th></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>                                                
       <tr>
         <td>Einbaudatum:</td><td class="sgn"> &nbsp; </td>
         <td>Name</td><td class="sgn"> &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>Anlaufprobleme:</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td colspan="2">Bitte Grund angeben</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: First question that pops up: why do you use tables?

Comment: I agree with @Roy. Table isn't the right semantic element for this content. It also makes styling harder.

Comment: @Roy: For lack of an better, easier idea. How would you solve it - is a solution using flexbox with divs easier?

Comment: Yes, flexbox is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would achieve that spacing with `::before` and `::after` pseudo classes.

1. First,  give elements you want to give space a unique class (e.g. `.spaced`).

```html
<td class="spaced sgn" colspan="3"> &nbsp; </td>
```

2. Then, give it a `relative` position so `::before` and `::after` get positioned relative to it:

```css
.spaced {
  position: relative;
}
```

3. Add `::before` and `::after` with the `width` you want as space, and position them to left and right respectively:

```css
.spaced::before,
.spaced::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: white;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
}

.spaced::before {
  left: 0;
}

.spaced::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/xxPJoQL?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

> What approach would you take if you had to create something that looks like the image above?

CSS Pseudo elements are perfect for this use case.

```css
.sgn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted blue;
  width: 20%;
}
```

You can adjust this to your liking, I couldn't figure out what width to get it to work but I'm sure you will be able to.

Comment: It is not clear how to make your code work with mine. The border `.sgn::after` is positioned above the other borders. See [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/YzEOKoV)

Comment: I [updated the codepen](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/JjOeGrr?editors=1000) so that it contains fewer markup and style rules. Do you know why some dotted lines are more at the top instead of the bottom?